# How to use logger.net for logging exceptions in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, .net, logger.net

I searched in Google for an example regarding logger.net. But I didn't find any proper solution. It only stores log details not exceptions.

Answer (score -1):

Configuration Files

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="Log" type="Zivsoft.Log.Handler,Zivsoft.Log"/>
  </configSections>
  <Log level="DEBUG">
    <LogFile>log.log</LogFile>
    <Console len="3">true</Console>
    <XmlLog enabled="true">log.xml</XmlLog>
    <ShowHeader>false</ShowHeader>
  </Log>
</configuration>
```

Sample code

```
using System;
using Zivsoft.Log;

namespace LogTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Logger.LogDebug("debug"); //log for debug
            Logger.LogError("error"); //log for error
            Logger.LogInfo("Info"); //log for information
            Logger.LogWarning("Warning"); //log for warning 
            Console.Read(); //pause the console
            try
            {
              int i=55/0;
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
               Logger.LogDebug(ex.Message); //log for Exception 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no `static void Main` method in ASP.NET.

Comment: Hi abhishek both information log and error log store in single file.But i need to store informationlog in one file and error log in anotherfile using logger.net

Comment: Hello @narasimhulu, in catch block before calling logger change the logger file path something like,

Logger.DefaultBinaryFile.Directory = "C:\\Logs";
// and/or
Logger.DefaultTextFile.Directory = "C:\\Logs";

Comment: Hello @abhishek, Logger.DefaultBinaryFile.Directory or Logger.DefaultTextFile.Directory is not exist in logger.net

Comment: which logger package and version you are using?

Comment: I use logger package zivsoft.log (version number:0.7.0.8) and .net framework 4.5

Comment: ok, Use FileLogger class to seperate the log file for different type to logs. while creating the different objects use FileLogger(LogLevel logLevel,string logFile,bool isShowHeader) constructor to initalize the values.